# Lazily interleaving pure computations contained inside IO monads

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

Is there some route for intelligently lazily interleaving mutually dependent pure computations that arise after IO operations?  I'm reading two config files, the first identifies the second, but the second determines the interpretation of the first.

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS
main = do
     ...
     f_state <- BS.readFile fn_state 
     let cfg_state' = procStateConfig' f_state
     f_base <- BS.readFile $ cfg_base_fn cfg_state'
     let cfg_base = procBaseConfig f_base
     let cfg_state = procStateConfig f_state cfg_base
     ...
```

I'm curious if I could avoid writing this extra function `procStateConfig'` by making `procBaseConfig` and `procStateConfig` mutually recursive in that each executes until it requires information from the other.

In particular, I could perhaps replace `procStateConfig'` by `procBaseConfig f_state undefined` if I ignore all the stuff that depends upon `cfg_base`, but this doesn't work quite so naively.

I imagine this might work if I didn't need the record `cfg_state`'s `cfg_base_fn` element for the second `BS.readFile`, but currently it looks hard.  And I'd rather fold both `BS.readFile` calls into the `proc..` cals anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle, laziness makes it possible. The problem here is that you need to do I/O based on the first `readFile`'s result. Ordinary Haskell doesn't allow recursive bindings in do-blocks, but the GHC extension `DoRec` does. I've never used it, so I may make some mistakes, but

```
{-# LANGUAGE DoRec #-}
module Main where

import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS

main = do
    ...
  { f_state <- BS.readFile fn_state
  ; rec { let cfg_state = procStateConfig f_state cfg_base
        ; cfg_base <- fmap procBaseConfig $ BS.readFile $ cfg_base_fn cfg_state
        }
  ; ...
  }
```

should do it. (At least, filling in some dummy `undefined`s, it compiles.)

Comment: If you want, you can avoid `DoRec` by reformulating it to use `mfix`